# deleting text only after comment(--)

Tags: c#, text

My project is currently spposd to delete all thetext after the -- signs, as it represents a comment.
my code now is deleting all the text in the text in the text file, een before the comment.

here is my code so far:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        string line = null;
        string line_to_delete = "--";
        string desktopLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop );
        string text = Path.Combine( desktopLocation, "tim3.txt" );
        string file = Path.Combine( desktopLocation, "tim4.txt" );

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( text ))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( file ))
            {
                while (( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null)
                {
                    if (string.Compare( line, line_to_delete ) == 0)
                        File.WriteAllText( file, File.ReadAllText( text ).Replace( line_to_delete, "" ) );
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

how can i specify that it must only delete the te
Thanks

Comment: why again same question ? possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618334/how-to-write-into-one-text-file

Comment: its not the same question. i want to find out here how to specfy that only text after thetwo --dashes must be removed.so if its --aa then that is fine but aa--aa must leave aa in the front.

Comment: Try my answer below, it is very simple and should accomplish exactly what you need to do.  It takes a string and deletes all characters after and including "--"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the fact that the replace (and this is the only instruction writing to your output file) would happen only when the file contains a line which is exactly equal to "--".

Furthermore you don't need the while loop if you are using WriteAllText and ReadAllText, and you can't use them anyway since in this way you would only delete the "--" and not everything that comes after that.

I think that something like this should work:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( text ))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( file ))
    {
        while (( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null)
        {
            int idx = line.IndexOf(line_to_delete);
            if (idx == 0) // just skip the whole line
                continue;
            if (idx > 0)
                writer.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, idx));
            else
                writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a RegEx or the following code

```
var @index = line.IndexOf(line_to_delete);
if(@index != -1){
    var commentSubstring = line.Substring(@index, line.Length - @index); //Contains only the comments
    line.Replace(commentSubstring, "").ToString()//Contains the original with no comments
}
```

If the comments are in the layout below

Blah blah -- some comment
--more comments

adasdasd
asfasffa

asasff --more comments

Comment: i have tried both code blocks but it has no change at all. i tried the regex but i have no idea how to use it. it seems to be the popular choice.

Comment: The encoding of the text file must not be Unicode which is the standard encoding used in C#... determine what encoding is used in the file and see if the RegEx needs to be modified. As for it not chaining anything... Maybe your file didn't have any comments :P Please elaborate

Comment: .. and for usage examples of RegEx in C# see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 2):

s.indexOF  searches for the first time "--" is used
s.remove starts at indexof and removes everything to the end.
**EDIT:**  fixed exception as per Jays comment

```
        string s = "aa--aa";
        int i = s.IndexOf("--");
        if (i >= 0)
            s = s.Remove(i);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Or here I one lined it for you

```
        string s = "aa--aa";
        s = s.IndexOf("--") >= 0 ? s.Remove(s.IndexOf("--")) : s;
```

Comment: This will except if '--' is not found because Remove cannot take a negative index... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx This deserves a down vote... lam3r

Comment: Thanks Jay I fixed it.  And thanks for the "lam3r" response, reminded me of my highschool days, you need that every once in a while

Comment: No problem, 1 is glad to be after 0 :P ( to be after 0 = of service )... Propz... And you should upvote my comment and answer because of this incident :P (this is not a request)

Comment: @Jay Your comment gets an upvote, but as for your answer...  Ok it's ugly but it serves the purpose.  Gotta love it though, we have the answer here an hour ago, and someone else comes in last minute and gets all the credit

Comment: Why thank you K'Leg, my reputation hurts less because of you! I will remember this in the after life / nether world of the force!

Comment: You missed the inline keyword on your 1 liner ;)... and you call the IndexOf function twice... if the JITer wasn't as good as it was then I would have to decapitate you :P My example is better it deserves more votes. Strings are immutable and since you are not doing any fancy mutating the string being created is just hidden away in your example... in mine you can at least perform meta processing.

Comment: @Jay You mean to tell me 13 hours later you came back to poke more holes in my answer...... :)  But in all seriousness what keyword did I miss?  I know I used indexof twice, I figured it wouldn't matter all that much.

Comment: K'Leg, if I tell you and I happen to be wrong you will hold it against me... instead I will state it as it was an attempt to receive more rep :P